# Как сложить два DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, арифметика

Имеется 2 DataFrame:

```
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
```

И

```
[2, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 2]
```

Индексы и названия столбцов в обоих случаях абсолютно одинаковые.

Каким методом мне правильнее будет воспользоваться, чтобы на выходе получить DataFrame видa:

```
[3, 4, 3]
[3, 4, 3]
[3, 4, 3]
```

Не могу разобраться как и что мне использовать.

Comment: `res = df1 + df2` Проще было попробовать чем писать вопрос ;)

Comment: Чёрт, реально работает, а я уже два часа тыкаюсь с merge, join и concat :\
Спасибо

Comment: вы бы сначала прочитали документацию -_-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для объекта pandas.DataFrame переопределены арифметические операторы, поэтому можно просто сложить два фрейма:

```
res = df1 + df2
```

Это будет правильно работать только в том случае, если совпадают наименования столбцов и значения индексов (порядок столбцов / индексов может различаться). При выполнении арифметических операций между фреймами Pandas сначала делает выравнивание по столбцам и строкам. Поэтому следующий пример отработает правильно даже несмотря на несовпадающий порядок столбцов:

```
In [30]: d1
Out[30]:
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1

In [31]: d2
Out[31]:
   c  a  b
0  2  2  3
1  2  2  3
2  2  2  3

In [32]: d1 + d2
Out[32]:
   a  b  c
0  3  4  3
1  3  4  3
2  3  4  3
```

---

Если же нам нужно прибавить значения совпадающего по размерности фрейма, но с отличными столбцами/индексами то это можно сделать прибавив к датафрейму Numpy матрицу *совпадающей размерности* (обратите внимание на несовпадающие столбцы и индексы):

```
In [37]: d1
Out[37]:
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1

In [38]: d3
Out[38]:
    X  Y  Z
11  4  5  4
12  4  5  4
13  4  5  4

In [39]: d1 + d3.to_numpy()
Out[39]:
   a  b  c
0  5  6  5
1  5  6  5
2  5  6  5
```